# Firebase functions pubsub multiple schedules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a function with one schedule:

```
exports = module.exports = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 12 hours')
```

How can I export this function to run at (0 0 * * *) and (12 0 * * * ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cron syntax](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) allows providing multiple values for a given time unit slot: "0,12 0 * * *"

Comment: I'ts true, shame on me, I forget. Thanks.

Comment: For executing at 12 noon and 12 midnight the Cron syntax should be ```0 0,12 * * *```. ```0,12 0 * * *``` will be for 12:00 AM and 12:12 AM and won't serve same as ```functions.pubsub.schedule('every 12 hours')```